# Помогите разобраться с jmap

Tags: java, jvm

В туториалах видел, что раньше по jmap -heap  можно было получить в консоль информацию по параметрам кучи в процессе. В моей нынешней версии jmap так сделать нельзя, есть только
jmap -dump:live,format:b,file=heap.bin , но он сохраняет данные в файл в нечитаемом бинарном формате.
Как получить с помощью jmap информацию по куче именно в консоль (не в графический интерфейс) в Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Закрываю вопрос.
В новых версиях jdk:

```
jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <pid number>
```